# RAILS: Using scopes to return counts and compute a percentage for a user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
Class Order < ActiveRecord::Base

  scope :ordered, lambda { |user| where("orders.user_id = ?", user.id) }
  scope :delivered, lambda { |user| where("orders.user_id = ? and orders.delivered = ?", user.id, true) }

  def self.delivered_percentage (user)
    ((self.ordered(user).count/self.delivered(user).count) * 100)
  end

end
```

I have an Order model, and I need to find out

1. The count of ordered items
2. The count of delivered items
3. The percentage of delivered items.

The ordered and delivered methods return an array. How do I have them return a count, and compute the percentage of delivered items.

In my controller I would like to

```
Order(current_user).delivered_percentage
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ordered` and `delivered` return `ActiveRecord::Relation`. If you call `count` on it, result of SQL `count` query will be returned. So your approach basically should work - except you have to convert your counts into floats to make it work:

```
def self.delivered_percentage(user)
  (ordered(user).count.to_f / delivered(user).count.to_f) * 100
end
```

and you call it with:

```
Order.delivered_percentage(current_user)
```

Comment: Thanks, let me try this. Also, is there a way to test the Ordered and Delivered scopes using rspec? When I use "it {should respond_to(:ordered(user)) } it fails with a syntax error

Comment: @learning_to_swim how many queries do you expect? I expect it to run two count queries - and it's perfectly ok.

Answer (score 1):

```
Order.group('delivered').count
```

That will return a hash: {true => 10, false => 33} with a single SQL query.

So you should be able to do this:

```
def self.delivered_percent(user)
  delivered_counts ||= Order.group('delivered').where(user: user).count
  delivered_counts[true]/delivered_counts.values.sum.to_f
end
```